# Ruby - Wrong number of argument (1/2)

Tags: ruby

The question is that when I tried with a Product it works, but with a Fruit doesn´t and came this error:

```
shoppingCart.rb:7:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (Argument
Error)
        from shoppingCart.rb:21:in `initialize'
        from shoppingCart.rb:37:in `new'
        from shoppingCart.rb:37:in `<main>'
```

Code:

```
class Product
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :price
  attr_accessor :discount


  def initialize(name, price)
    @name = name
    @price = price
  end

  def calculatePrice
    puts "The price of the #{@name} is #{@price} euros"
  end

end

class Fruit < Product

  def initialize(name, price)
    super(name)
    super(price)
  end

  def discount()
    @discount = 10
  end
end

banana = Fruit.new("banana", 10)
banana.calculatePrice
```

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? It is clear what is being asked even if it is poorly worded.

Comment: I cannot understand why, Im simply learning how to use ruby with same examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `super` from `Fruit#initialize`, it's calling `Product#initialize`, which takes two arguments.  So call it once with both arguments, instead of once each:

```
super(name, price)
```

Since those are the same arguments that `Fruit#initialize` itself takes, you can also just leave them off to automatically pass along the same ones:

```
super
```

But since you aren't doing anything `Fruit`-specific in `Fruit#initialize`, you can delete that method entirely to get the same result:

```
class Product 
  def initialize(name, price)
     puts "Into Product#Initialize"
  end
end

class Fruit < Product
end

banana = Fruit.new(banana, 10)
# Into Product#Initialize
# => #<Fruit:0x007f9da91cef00>
```

Comment: Calling `super` without any arguments would work too.

Comment: Perfect! It works and easily to understands, I will be more carefull next time.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error because you call `super` with one argument in `Fruit#initialize`, but `Product#initialize` takes two arguments. Since you don't do anything specific to `Fruit` in `Fruit#initialize` method, you don't need this method at all.